# Texture changes between object and edit mode

Tags: texturing

Me again! I've been working on the texture for a model, but when I switched to edit mode to take a look at it, it got totally changed up. Does anyone know why this is happening? (And, if I export the model, which version will it have?)

[image: edit mode vs object mode]

My .blend file is here, if it helps!
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38433

Comment: What modifiers do you have? Some may be disabled in Edit mode

Comment: I don't have any modifiers.

Comment: @amymist please pack the textures in your file.

Comment: The model have a series of extra faces that you can see in object mode. Clean the extra faces on the mouth zone.

Comment: Cleaning up the extra faces fixed it, thanks! That said, I'm still really curious about why it did it in the first place.